# How to change the font in awesome-cv?

Tags: fonts, overleaf, awesome-cv

How do I change the font in awesome-cv? I detest the Roberto font and would like to revert back to the default latex font with math support.

I am perusing this version from Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/tvmzpvdjfqxp

Edit:
Is there a way to change the body text size to 12pt? I tried setting it in the options for the document class, to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "boxy text"? Are you referring to "body text"?

Comment: Change the `11pt` option in the `\documentclass` optional argument to `12pt`.

Comment: That (changing font to 12pt in \documentclass did not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did the main document font *not* change to 12pt? If not, did it change at all? Did you layout change? What happened...?

Comment: The text font size did not change. I even tried 24pt just for kicks, to no avail.

Comment: Can you send an image with `11pt` and one with `12pt` so I can see the difference? When I change the document class option to `12pt`, it changes the layout so less stuff fits on the first page (an indication that the font size/baseline skip changed).

Comment: @Werner https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/57

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're working in an online template, you can change the `.cls` to suit your needs.

[Overleaf's Awesome CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/tvmzpvdjfqxp#.WGG_1fnR_Dc) loads all the fonts in the `fonts/` older within the project. If you don't want to use `Roborto`, edit lines 177-216 of `awesome-cv.cls` where the "configuration for fonts" are set. Specifically, the class defines the following font families:

```
\newfontfamily\headerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{Roboto}

\newfontfamily\headerfontlight[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Thin,
  ItalicFont=*-ThinItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Medium,
  BoldItalicFont=*-MediumItalic,
]{Roboto}

% Set font for footer (default is Source Sans Pro)
\newfontfamily\footerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-It,
  BoldFont=*-Bold
]{SourceSansPro}

% Set font for body (default is Source Sans Pro)
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-It,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt
]{SourceSansPro}

\newfontfamily\bodyfontlight[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Light,
  ItalicFont=*-LightIt,
  BoldFont=*-Semibold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-SemiboldIt
]{SourceSansPro}
```

where `\@fontdir` points to the `fonts/` folder.

Upload a new font into the `fonts/` folder and update the above. If you just want good ol' Computer Modern, you can add

```
\let\headerfont\rmfamily
\let\headerfontlight\rmfamily
\let\footerfont\rmfamily
\let\bodyfont\rmfamily
\let\bodyfontlight\rmfamily
```

just before `\begin{document}` in `resume.tex`.

[image]

Note that with a change in font there is most certainly going to be a change in layout (as can be seen by the sectional unit ending without content at the bottom of the first page).