# Change Font in the entire Awesome CV Cover Letter to Times New Roman?

Tags: awesome-cv

I would like to change the font in the complete Cover Letter: https://www.overleaf.com/project/63b551027b1fff39eabd1fa8

to Times New Roman.

I've seen threads like here
[How to change the font in awesome-cv?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345803/how-to-change-the-font-in-awesome-cv)

but as there are several different ways of changing the font, or rather different commands, as sometimes you need a short code for it as seen here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX#The_basics:_Times_New_Roman

I'm not sure how to do it.

I've managed to change the font in the main body with this:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}

        {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont    text bla bla}
```

which I found here: \usepackage{mathptmx}

But I also want to change the header and the addressee, etc.

So, how do I change the complete document to Times New Roman?
Cheers

Comment: Please share your  oveleaf project.

Comment: I don't have an overleaf project, but can you use this as an example? https://www.overleaf.com/5917327472cdyfkdkyxddj

Comment: Try the solution form https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345806/161015